# Having trouble with undefined terms in a Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

So...I am trying to find the Fourier series for the following function:

$
f(t)=
\begin{cases}
 0&\text{if}\, -\pi\leq t\lt -\pi/2\\
 \cos(t)&\text{if}\, -\pi/2\leq t\leq \pi/2\\
      0&\text{if}\, \pi/2\lt t\leq \pi\\
\end{cases}
$

Where its period,$T$, is $2\pi$ and thus $w=2\pi/T=1$

When I try to find out the terms, I have the following:

$a[0]=\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}cos(t)dt=2$

$a[n]=\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}cos(t)cos(nwt)dt=\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}cos(t)cos(nt)dt=-\frac{(2cos((\frac{\pi n}{2}))}{(n^2-1)}$

$b[n]=\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}cos(t)sin(nwt)dt=\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}cos(t)sin(nt)dt=0$ (even function)

Where the weirdness starts...
If I evaluate some terms, it's noticeable that the $n=1$ term is not defined. Is that even possible, or did I make a mistake?

Comment: I suggest doing the calculation for $n=1$ separately (and carefully).

Comment: Oh! So, If I evaluate the integral of $a[1]$, I will get $\pi/2$. I guess that by starting the fourier series at $n=2$ and adding  $\pi/2$ to it at the start, it's a valid definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If the general term is not define for some $n$ , then you can separately calculate the term. Suppose it is mentioned in question, is at $n=1$ the coefficient is *not defined* so you have to substitute $n=1$ in the formula of $a_n$
So if you put $n=1$ in the formula for $a_n$ then it appears as
$$a_1 = \frac{1} {\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\cos{{x} } $$
Now you can substitue the value of $f(x)$ and calculate $a_1$
Where $ L = \pi $ (half of the period)

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}cos(t)cos(nt) dt = \frac12\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\bigl(cos((1-n) t) + cos((1+n) t)\bigr)dt$$
Here is the problem. You can't integrate the expression now because the argument of the first cosine might be zero. So you now have to divide it to two cases: $n=1$ and $n>1$.

First case:
$$\frac12\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\bigl(1 + cos((1+n) t)\bigr)dt = \frac12\bigl[t+\frac{1}{1+n}sin((1+n)t)\bigr]_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Second case:
$$\frac12\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\bigl(cos((n-1) t) + cos((1+n) t)\bigr)dt = \frac12\bigl[\frac{1}{n-1}sin((n-1)t)+\frac{1}{1+n}sin((1+n)t)\bigr]_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Now it leads to straightforward calculation. All needed terms are now defined.

By the way, you shoud divide $a_0$ by $2\pi$.

EDIT: You need to divide $a_0$ by $2\pi$ and all other coefficients by $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks! I had actually forgotten to multiply those integrals by 2/T. Shouldn't $a_0$ be divided by $\pi$ then (And $a_n$, too)?

Comment: The $a_0$ is the average value, so you need to divide it by the lenght of whole period. Also, I recalled that you need to divide all other coefficients by $\pi$. The reason is more complicated.